# How to limit number of images being printer out in "Set Featured Image" pop up?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I have wordpress web site which contains over 150 000 images and when you click on "Set Featured Image" whole server slows down. Another thing is that it take a really long time to load images.

Is there any filter/action/hook to add pager or to just show last 10 images.

Another question is how to optimize whole thing (maybe images sort by subfolders with some plugin) so it can work

Comment: There's only so much you could do to optimize the system.. Posts, pages, revisions and attachments all share the same database table which means that it's probably huge. Have you upgraded your hardware along with your site growth? If you query posts, pages or attachements, it will need to load the whole table to server's memory and if it doesn't fit to memory, it's **A LOT slower**.

Comment: What are the slow SQL queries here? Is it only the "Set Featured Image" media view that's slow and not the "Add Media" view? It should be paginated via ajax when you scroll down. The month-year query can be slow on large sites and also the video/audio queries. See e.g. [#31071](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31071)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update 1:

After dived into core AJAX call, this filter will only happen on `post.php` page:

```
add_filter('ajax_query_attachments_args', function($query){
    if ( isset($_POST['post_id']) && !empty($_POST['post_id']) ) {
        $query['posts_per_page'] = 10; // output 10 images only.
    }
    return $query;
});
```

---

1. You can use [`ajax_query_attachments_args`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php#L2385) filter:

```
add_filter('ajax_query_attachments_args', function($query){
    $query['posts_per_page'] = 10; // output 10 images only.
    return $query;
});
```

2. Because of querying attachments happens in core and using AJAX, I don't think we can optimize the whole thing.

Comment: This was my first thought, but unfortunately setting `posts_per_page` to anything different from `-1` will break the infinite scroll. Another point is that this has a global scope, affecting not just the featured image in post types but the Media Library manager.