# How to limit the number of images displayed in the media window?

Tags: images, uploads, media-library

I have a lot of images in my website, so when I open `wp-admin/upload.php` the server slow down.
Would be possible to display only 50 images per time?

I saw there is [this similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226255/how-to-limit-number-of-images-being-printer-out-in-set-featured-image-pop-up), but it works only for the "set featured image" popup.

I would like to apply the limit also to the `upload.php` window.

How can I achieve that?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this other similar question (with a good answer) can help you.
[Change default screen option value for media items per page (in media library)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143661/change-default-screen-option-value-for-media-items-per-page-in-media-library)

And the filter to use is :

```
function my_edit_media_per_page(){
    $media_per_page = 200; //or whatever you want
    return $media_per_page;
}

add_filter( 'upload_per_page', 'my_edit_media_per_page', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: I added this to `function.php` but it returns all the media, why?

Comment: Do you use the library in list or grid mode?
Do you have any plugins installed, affecting the media library?